# On Form Submission trigger on GAS but ss.getLastRow(); doesn't give me the latest entry

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form where you choose between A or B to get to Section A or Section B of the form.

My code looks like this:

```html
const startTrigger = () => {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("main")
    .forForm(FORM_ID)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

const main = () => {
 //Extracting latest submission
  var responses = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FORM_RESPONSE_ID).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = responses.getLastRow();
  var data = responses.getRange(lastRow,1,1,24).getValues();

  //Choice of A or B
  var CHOICE_TYPE = data[0][2];

  Logger.log(CHOICE_TYPE);
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  if (CHOICE_TYPE=== "A"){
    //<code block>
    
  }

  else if (CHOICE_TYPE === "B"){
    //<code block>
  }

  }
```

When I submit a form the trigger successfully runs the main() function. However, when you choose "A" it extracts the last entry instead of the newly submitted one and runs the code with that last data. When you choose "B" it works fine! It takes the new entry and runs the code normally.

I don't understand why there is a difference when choosing these options.

Comment: About `However, when you choose "A" it extracts the last entry instead of the newly submitted one and runs the code with that last data. When you choose "B" it works fine! It takes the new entry and runs the code normally.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, can I ask you about the reason that you don't use the event object? Because I thought that when the event object is used, the submitted values can be also retrieved.

Comment: This is all the important information. That's why it's weird because I expect it to work but it doesn't. Then, after not doing anything and running it again it worked fine. I'm not sure if this is a GAS bug. I currently used SpreadsheetApp.flush() to make sure the sheet data are updated before running the script and so far so good. If It still breaks now I would assume it's a bug somewhere on GSheets or GAS

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: What do you mean by `when you choose "A" it extracts the last entry instead of the newly submitted one and runs the code with that last data.`? What extracts the last entry? If you mean the last row then it'll always be the last row defined by `var lastRow = responses.getLastRow();`

Comment: Oh let's say there are currently N rows, the new form submission should be row N+1. When I choose "A" lastRow gives me N (instead of N+1), while "B", lastRow gives me N+1 with no problem.

Comment: Can you share a dummy sheet that can be played with?